# Evitar que ejecute varias veces la ubicacion

Tags: javascript, html5

Tengo este codigo:

```js
let map, marker, watchId, geoLoc, autocomplete;
function initMap() {
    const myLatLng = {lat:3.458619536736577, lng:-73.12320051171845};
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
                zoom:5,
                center: myLatLng,
        });
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map,
            title: "Esto es colombia",
            draggable: true
        });
            getPosition();
            IautoComplete();
            draggEvente();
    }

    function getPosition() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            var options ={
                timeout: 5000
            };
            geoLoc = navigator.geolocation;
            watchId = geoLoc.watchPosition(showLocationOnMap, errorHandler, options);
        }else{
            alert("Lo sentimos, el explorador no soporta geolocalizacion")
        }
    }

    function showLocationOnMap(position) {
        var latitud = position.coords.latitude;
        var longitud = position.coords.longitude;
        console.log("Latitud: "+ latitud +", " + "Longitud: "+ longitud);

        const myLatLng = {lat: latitud, lng: longitud};
        marker.setPosition(myLatLng);
        map.setCenter(myLatLng);
    }

    function errorHandler(err) {
        if (err.code == 1){
            alert("Error: Acceso denegado!");
        } else if(err.code == 2){
            alert("Error: Position no existe o no encontrada");
        }
    }

    function IautoComplete() {
        const autput = document.getElementById("places_input");

        autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(autput);
        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
            const place = autocomplete.getPlace();
            
            map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
            marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
            console.log(place.geometry.location);
            autocomplete.bindTo("bounds", map);
        })
    }

    function draggEvente() {
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'drag', function (event) {
            let lan =(event.latLng.lat());
            let lon =(event.latLng.lng());
            let lanlon = lan+","+lon;
            console.log(lanlon)
        })
    }
```

```css
/* 
 * Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div element
 * that contains the map. 
 */
 #map {
    height: 100%;
  }
  
  /* 
   * Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. 
   */
  html,
  body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  input{
    width: 100%;
    height: 5%;
    border-radius:0%;
    border: none;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=head">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>GoogelMaps</title>
    <script src="indes.js"></script>

     <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
     <script
     src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR-KEY-API&libraries=places&callback=initMap&v=weekly"
     defer
   ></script>
   
   

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />

</head>

<body>
    <input  type="text"  id="places_input" placeholder="Ingrese direccion">

    <div>
        <form action="direccion" method="get">
            <div>
                <select name="nomeclatura" id="nomeclatura">
                    <option value="0">Seleccionar</option>
                    <option value="1">Calle</option>
                    <option value="2">Carrera</option>
                    <option value="3">Transversal</option>
                    <option value="4">Diagonal</option>
                    <option value="5">Avenida</option>
                    <option value="6">Bulevar</option>
                    <option value="7">Autopista</option>
                    <option value="8">Esquina</option>
                    <option value="9">Travesia</option>
                </select>
                <input type="text" name="txtPrincipal" id="txtPrincipal" placeholder="Numero Principal">
                <input type="text" name="txtSecundario" id="txtSecundario" placeholder="Numero Secundario">
                <input type="text" name="txtCasa" id="txtCasa" placeholder="Numero Casa">

                <input type="button" value="Aceptar">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <br>
    <hr>
    <div id="map"></div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

El problema esta en que en la consola me muestra que la peticion de ubicacion se realiza varias veces y si muevo el marcador este regresa a la ubicacion original y no debe ser asi

ya que esto usa API KEY no puedo dejarles la mia por cuestiones legales